# How to calcute Euler number in opencv and python

Tags: python, opencv

I am newbie in text detection and I try to do a matlab tutorial with opencv and matlab, in this tutorial, we need to calculate a "Geometric Properties" to Remove Non-Text Regions like 
1- Eccentricity
2- Euler number

the problem is, I don't find in the documentation of python's opencv a function to calculte them, I founded this pages "http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d1/d32/tutorial_py_contour_properties.html" but it seems to be incomplete

Please if anyone know how to calculate it, please advice me

Thanks

Comment: *Euler number* is `e ~ 2.71828...`?

Comment: I am sorry, but i made a mistake, in the article, it's mentionned that we can apply some geometric propreties, and one of this proprties is euler number, I don't understand how to appl it to an image, do I need to multiply my images with euler number, please can you help me ?

Comment: there is no way to help you with understanding algorithm without algorithm provided

Comment: You can use Skimage measure region properties after connected components.  See https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.measure.html#skimage.measure.euler_number

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can calculate the Euler no but not with openCV but in python there is a Library mahotas.
Description : https://mahotas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

This library is also quite fast as implemented in C++

```
import mahotas
import numpy as np
from pylab import gray, imshow, show
import os

# loading image
img = mahotas.imread('dog_image.png')


# filtering image
img = img[:, :, 0]

# otsu method
T_otsu = mahotas.otsu(img)

# image values should be greater than otsu value
img = img > T_otsu

print("Image threshold using Otsu Method")

# showing image
imshow(img)
show()


# euler number of image of image
euler = mahotas.euler(img)

print("Euler Number of Image : " + str(euler))
```